# Using EF core and EF6 side-by-side

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-core-3.0

I have a .NET Core 3.0 solution that contains 5 projects. One of the projects uses EF6, and another one uses EF Core, so EF6 and EF Core are being used side-by-side. Visual Studio is as fresh as possible (16.3.5). Trying to create migration for the project that uses EF6 and executing the Add-Migration command on my laptop with Windows 10 I see a warning message: *"Both Entity Framework 6 and Entity Framework Core are installed. The Entity Framework 6 tools are running. Use 'EntityFrameworkCore\Update-Database' for Entity Framework Core"*, but all goes fine and migration completes successfully.

The Get-Module command displays the following table:

```
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------                                                                            
Script     6.3.0      EntityFramework6                    {Add-EFDefaultConnectionFactory, Add-EFProvider, Add-Migration, Enable-Migrations...}
Script     3.0.0      EntityFrameworkCore                 {Add-Migration, Drop-Database, Enable-Migrations, Get-DbContext...}
Script     2.0.0.0    NuGet                               {Add-BindingRedirect, Find-Package, Get-Package, Get-Project...}
Script     0.0        profile
```

On another workstation with Windows 7 onboard, running the same command I see almost the same table but with empty list of cmdlets exported by EF6:

```
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------                                                                            
Script     6.3.0      EntityFramework6                    
Script     3.0.0      EntityFrameworkCore                 {Add-Migration, Drop-Database, Enable-Migrations, Get-DbContext...}
Script     2.0.0.0    NuGet                               {Add-BindingRedirect, Find-Package, Get-Package, Get-Project...}
Script     0.0        profile
```

Eventually, in such a case I can't perform migrations on EF6-bound project at all. How could I fix that? Neither 'Add-Migration' nor 'EntityFramework\Add-Migration' nor 'EntityFrameworkCore\Add-Migration' won't work.

**UPDATE 17 oct 2019**
That seems to me that my VS installation is corrupted. The good news is that EF6.3 comes with the ef.exe utility that replaces migrate.exe and allows a developer to create migrations using command line outside VS IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Create an additional solution(s) with only your EF6 or only your EFCore dependent project(s) and do what version-specific actions need to be done while using that solution.

Comment: Following your advise I tried to move EF6.3-dependent project to additional solution located in the same directory, then moved that solution to another directory, then cleaned out all the projects with deletion of "bin" and "obj" folders, then tried to reinstall EF using Uninstall-Package and Install-Package commands, then removed EF6 from Nuget cache folder and reinstalled EF6; finally I deleted EF6 and EF core from nuget cache and installed EF6.4 preview. But with no avail. The Get-Module command still shows no exported cmdlets from EF6.